# unpack string in variable

Tags: variables, zsh

In Bash, I can use the following code:

```
[ "$sshcmd" = "" ] && sshcmd="ssh -someopts myhost"

$sshcmd "echo hello world"
```

In ZSH, the same code does not work because it tries to find a "ssh -someopts myhost" executable. How can I do the same thing in ZSH?

Thanks, Albert

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: @Dennis: I am the second case but in my case, the user passes the command via a parameter or via an env-variable to the script. Or if he does not, the script uses some default. How would I solve this?

Comment: You'll probably have to use the suggestions in the answer (and comment) below (which are consistent with the information at that link). However, you should be aware that there are potential security implications of executing commands passed as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split a string at whitespace (more generally, at `$IFS`) like other shells: `$=sshcmd`

But you should instead make `sshcmd` an array, so that your commands still works if one of the options contains whitespace:

```
sshcmd=(ssh -someopts myopts)
$sshcmd[@] "echo hello world"
```

This applies to bash and ksh too, by the way; but there you must also protect the array variable substitution against further splitting and filename expansion:

```
sshcmd=(ssh -someopts myopts)
"${sshcmd[@]}" "echo hello world"
```

Comment: I am getting this via an environment from Bash, so I think an array is not an option (or how can I automatically convert it?). But `$=sshcmd` works, thanks!

Comment: @Albert To split something just like the shell does, use `${(z)sshcmd}`. It will handle the case when sshcmd contains quoted parameters: if sshcmd contains a string `a 'b c d'`, `$=sshcmd` will split it into `a`, `'b`, `c`, `d'`, while `${(z)sshcmd}` into `a`, `'b c d'`. It also handles `$(...)`, `"..."`, etc; see PARAMETER EXPANSION section in man zshexpn.

Comment: Thanks @ZyX, this seems much more useful!

Comment: @Albert: If in bash you'd use `$sshcmd`, then the zsh equivalent is `$=sshcmd`; you just can't have whitespace in options then, as the information of whether a space is a separator or part of the option has been lost. If in bash you'd use `eval $sshcmd`, then zsh comes close (but with saner quoting requirements) with `${(z)sshcmd}`; though zsh would be even more compatible with `(emulate sh; eval $sshcmd)`.